# Append strings to a variable and display them at the front of the document?

Tags: strings

Not sure about this - but some ideas would be helpful, I wanted to know how to append strings, then at the end display the strings at the start?  Is it possible?  Any examples?

For example, ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mystring{} % temp string
\def\myappendstring#1{ \myappendstring#1 }

\begin{document}

\mystring % how to display the final string here last? e.g., 'once upon a time'

Text...

\myappendstring{Once}

Text ...

\myappendstring{upon}

\myappendstring{a}

\myappendstring{time}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Write the string to an auxiliary file. Then read it back on the next run. The printed string will be one compilation behind, so compile twice to see changes. (Writing to the `.aux` or whatever would obviously do if you're just writing once.) Don't use `\def` in LaTeX unless you understand and accept the consequences. So `\mystring` does nothing and takes no arguments and `\myappendstring` takes one argument and creates an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

The system macro `\g@addto@macro` appends the 2nd argument to the macro cited in the 1st argument.

Combine that with writing out to the aux file, which ends up as

```
\relax
\@writefile{xyz}{\gdef \thefinalstring { Once upon a time}}
```

which writes `\gdef \thefinalstring { Once upon a time}` to the `.xyz` file.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mystring{} % temp string
\def\thefinalstring{} % Saved in aux file
\makeatletter
\def\myappendstring#1{\g@addto@macro\mystring{ #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{xyz}% executes stuff in .xyz file
\makeatother
\thefinalstring % display the final string here 

Text...

\myappendstring{Once}

Text ...

\myappendstring{upon}

\myappendstring{a}

\myappendstring{time}

\addtocontents{xyz}{\gdef\protect\thefinalstring{\mystring}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (How) can this method deal with `\myappendstring{\value{mycounter}}  \addtocounter{mycounter}{1}  \myappendstring{\value{mycounter}}` or other inputs that change over time?

Comment: @lucidbrot `\def\myappendxstring#1{\edef\tmp{#1}\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\mystring\expandafter{\tmp}}`.  Then, `\stepcounter{mycounter}
\myappendxstring{Counter value is \themycounter. }`

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about `\stepcounter` yet either

Answer (score 1):

Without appending any macros in your document (i.e. between `\begin{document}`...`\end{document}`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mystring{} % temp string
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\myappendstring#1{\immediate\write\csname @auxout\endcsname
   {\global\noexpand\addto\noexpand\mystring{ #1}}}

\begin{document}

\mystring % how to display the final string here last? e.g., 'once upon a time'

Text...

\myappendstring{Once}

Text ...

\myappendstring{upon}

\myappendstring{a}

\myappendstring{time}

\end{document}
```