# Print a list of items at the beginning, where each item is defined throughout the document

Tags: auxiliary-files

I would like to print a list of items at the beginning of a document, where each item is defined throughout the document.

How can I do this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\totalliste
This is shown in the document : Item1, Item2 <-desired output for the totalliste command

\addtoliste{Item1}
\addtoliste{Item2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the items in the `.aux` file, so they will be reread at the beginning of the next run.

The following also implements a check that warns you if the list has changed from the previous run.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_jowe_list_seq
\seq_new:N \l__jowe_list_old_seq
\bool_new:N \l__jowe_list_differ_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtoliste}{m}
 {
  \iow_shipout:cn { @mainaux } { \ADDTOLIST{#1} }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ADDTOLIST}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_jowe_list_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\totalliste}{}
 {
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \g_jowe_list_seq
   {
    ``The~list~is~empty''
   }
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \g_jowe_list_seq { ,~ }
   }
 }

\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}
 {
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l__jowe_list_old_seq \g_jowe_list_seq
  \seq_gclear:N \g_jowe_list_seq
 }

\AddToHook{enddocument/afteraux}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__jowe_list_old_seq != \seq_count:N \g_jowe_list_seq }
   {
    \typeout{***~List~changed,~rerun~LaTeX~***}
   }
   {
    \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN \l__jowe_list_old_seq \g_jowe_list_seq \__jowe_list_compare:nn
    \bool_if:NT \l__jowe_list_differ_bool
     {
      \typeout{***~List~changed,~rerun~LaTeX~***}
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jowe_list_compare:nn
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__jowe_list_differ_bool
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\totalliste

\section{Just for a divider}

Here we add some items to our list

\addtoliste{Item1}
\addtoliste{Item2}
\addtoliste{Item3}

\end{document}
```

In case the list differs from the previous run, you get

```
*** List changed, rerun LaTeX ***
```

on the console and in the log file.

[image]

For your particular case where the items are file names, possibly with underscores, I suggest this only change to the code above

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ADDTOLIST}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Ne \g_jowe_list_seq { \exp_not:N \texttt { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } }
 }
```

and then with

```
\addtoliste{file_name.py}
\addtoliste{Item2}
\addtoliste{Item3}
```

you'd get

[image]

#### Lists per chapter

If you want to print the list chapter by chapter, we must change the strategy a bit.

The idea is the same, but I add a step. At begin document the big sequence containing all items is split into subsequences, one for each chapter. The chapter number has been recorded together with the item.

Now `\totalliste` will use the subsequence relative to the current chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_jowe_list_seq
\seq_new:N \l__jowe_list_old_seq
\bool_new:N \l__jowe_list_differ_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtoliste}{m}
 {
  \iow_shipout:ce { @mainaux } { \ADDTOLIST{\arabic{chapter}}{\exp_not:n { #1 } } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ADDTOLIST}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_jowe_list_seq { \__jowe_list_item:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\totalliste}{}
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cTF { l__jowe_list_chapter_\arabic{chapter}_seq }
   {
    \seq_use:cn { l__jowe_list_chapter_\arabic{chapter}_seq } { ,~ }
   }
   {
    ``The~list~is~empty''
   }
 }

\AddToHook{begindocument/end}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_jowe_list_seq { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jowe_list_item:nn
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l__jowe_list_chapter_#1_seq }
   {% allocate the chapter sequence
    \seq_new:c { l__jowe_list_chapter_#1_seq }
   }
  \seq_put_right:cn { l__jowe_list_chapter_#1_seq } { \texttt { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } } }
 }

\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}
 {
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l__jowe_list_old_seq \g_jowe_list_seq
  \seq_gclear:N \g_jowe_list_seq
 }

\AddToHook{enddocument/afteraux}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__jowe_list_old_seq != \seq_count:N \g_jowe_list_seq }
   {
    \typeout{***~List~changed,~rerun~LaTeX~***}
   }
   {
    \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN \l__jowe_list_old_seq \g_jowe_list_seq \__jowe_list_compare:nn
    \bool_if:NT \l__jowe_list_differ_bool
     {
      \typeout{***~List~changed,~rerun~LaTeX~***}
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__jowe_list_compare:nn
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { #2 }
   {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__jowe_list_differ_bool
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\totalliste

\section{Just for a divider}

Here we add some items to our list

\addtoliste{file_name.py}
\addtoliste{Item2}
\addtoliste{Item3}

\chapter{Second}

\totalliste

\section{Just for a divider}

No item here

\chapter{Third}

\totalliste

\section{Just for a divider}

Here we add some items to our list

\addtoliste{file_name-again.py}
\addtoliste{Item2-3}
\addtoliste{Item3-3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But the items are in fact of the form `file_name.py` (python file name), so LaTeX fails to print the list because of the character `_`. Is it possible to adapt the previous code for this purpose ?

Comment: @jowe_19 I added a possible modification.

Comment: Thanks; is it possible to check if the list is empty or not ?

Comment: @jowe_19 Yes, of course. What do you *actually* want to do with that list?

Comment: I would like to print a message if the list is empty.

Comment: @jowe_19 I modified the definition of `\totalliste`

Comment: I've forgotten one more thing, but I promise it's my last request. Is it possible to get a command to empty the list? I'll use it every time I change chapters.

Comment: @jowe_19 I added the “by chapter” code. But you should have specified the requirement in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Needs to compile twice.  Possibly a duplicate of [Append strings to a variable and display them at the front of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402173/append-strings-to-a-variable-and-display-them-at-the-front-of-the-document), since this answer is largely based upon my answer there.

To have access to information in a document prior to its definition within the document, the standard approach is to write the information out to an auxiliary file on the first compilation, and then, on the second compilation, read that information in at the beginning of the document.  That is the approach taken here, with the information written to a file with a `.xyz` suffix, containing the line:

```
\gdef \totalliste {Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4}
```

This information, on later compilations, is read in at the beginning of the document, to provide the desired list at the beginning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mystring{} % temp string
\def\totalliste{} % Saved in aux file
\makeatletter
\def\addtoliste#1{\ifx\empty\mystring
  \g@addto@macro\mystring{#1}\else\g@addto@macro\mystring{, #1}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{xyz}% executes stuff in .xyz file
\makeatother
\totalliste % display the final string here 

Text...

\addtoliste{Item1}

Text ...

\addtoliste{Item2}

\addtoliste{Item3}

\addtoliste{Item4}

\addtocontents{xyz}{\gdef\protect\totalliste{\mystring}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this solution, which works well also.